# How to display all the sms' the user received and group them

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I am building an sms app to send and receive sms'.I am able to send and receive the sms'. I want the app to  show all the messages received by the user, even those that are received by the user before the app install and the messages should be grouped by the sender, i.e. All the messages sent by one sender can be seen together but don't have any idea how to do this.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want with this code, don't forget to add `android.permission.READ_SMS` permission on the manifest:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) // Check if there is SMS'
    do {
       String smsData = "";
       for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
           smsData += "\n" + cursor.getColumnName(i) + ":" + cursor.getString(i);
       }
       // TODO Do what you want with smsData
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
else
   // There's no SMS to show
```

Despite of that, there is no guarantee that this would work in all Android devices as this `ContentProvider` is not officially supported by the Android SDK and Google **does not recommed to use it** as you can read [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html).